# Can trigger.io be used with browserify?

Tags: javascript, trigger.io, browserify

I've just found out about trigger.io today and it looks interesting. One question I have though is, can it be used with browserify.

I've been getting used to writing my JS modules using browserify and I love the commonjs require pattern as it keeps all my files nicely isolated and it's easy to understand.

I'm wondering how `trigger.io` might work with browserify? I noticed at a glance in the docs that you seem to reference a global `forge` object in your code to access the native components. Would it be possible to instead do something like `var forge = require('trigger.io')` and have it work as expected?

I wasn't sure if trigger was distributed as an npm package, as this is how I do it with jQuery for instance. The docs just mention downloading a toolkit rather than installing through npm.

Has anyone used trigger.io with browserify?

Comment: Browserify is a bit like RequireJS correct? If that's the case, could you wrap window.forge in your own module and require the module in your code?

Comment: Browserify is NOT like requireJS, but they roughly solve the same problem. I'd have to see the source of trigger.io I guess. I know there is a way to wrap things that attach themselves to the window using browserify-shim.